# Reading File in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-io

I am trying to read a file (made a simple .txt file on my desktop for that purpose) from machine using Dart on Dartium browser.

I have an input field, added a listener to it and here is how it looks:

```
  void _onFileSelect(event) {
    dom.File file = _fileInput.files.item(0);

    dom.FileReader reader = new dom.FileReader();
    //reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

    reader.addEventListener('load', (event) {
      print(reader.result); // This is the line I am having the problem with.
    });

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

When I select the file, I get error:

> Stack Trace:  0. Function: 'Object.noSuchMethod' url: 'bootstrap' line:717 col:3

on the line I marked using an inline-comment.

I have also set up a script to execute Dartium with the required flag:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /opt/DartEditor/dart-sdk/chromium
./chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files $@
```

Can anyone give any tips where the problem could be?

P.S. I am using Ubuntu Precise x64.

Comment: Ok, i do not understand. You want to read a file not on "server-side" but client-side? And where should '''print(reader.result);''' display the text? I am a beginner too, but AFAIK when i used print, it only printed text in my console within DartEditor.

Comment: Yes, I want to read a local file. As I said, it's located on my desktop. Print, as far as I know, prints a message to the log, whatever it is. By default it prints it to DartEditor console but if you opened a web console in your browser, it would start printing there. I used this code just to test whether it can read the file and appearently it can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you can't use the dart:io libraries in Dartium. Those libraries only work on Dart VM on the command line.

You might want to use an XMLHttpRequest to read in the file from an HTTP server.